# Java IntStream or LongStream limit by value and not by count of elements

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to iterate / generate an infinite IntStream or LongStream and limit them by a provided max value, and not by the count of elements which is posible with the operation `limit(long n)`, for example to get the first 20 positive even numbers:

```
List<Integer> evens = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 2)
                               .limit(20)
                               .boxed()
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What I need is to limit the stream by a max value. If for example I need all powers of two under 1000

```
List<Integer> evens = IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i * 2)  //1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32...
                               .limit(<here some how use the value 1000>)
                               .boxed()
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or Fibonacci sequence

```
List<Long> fibs = Stream.iterate(new long[]{1,1}, f -> new long[]{f[1], f[0] + f[1]})  //1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21...
                        .mapToLong(f -> f[1])
                        .limit(i -> i < 1000) //I know this doesn't work as limit expects a long value
                        .boxed()
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Filter doesn't work and leads to `OutOfMemoryError`

```
List<Integer> evens = IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i * 2)  //1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32...
                               .filter(i -> i <= 1000)
                               .boxed()
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have many different `UnaryOperators` which I want to use to generate different sequences of numbers (not only the simple examples I gave above, like `i -> i * 2` where i could somehow calculate the possible count of the elements in a given range).

Question: how can I limit the stream by a given max value instaed of count of elements?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Java 9+, use `takeWhile(i -> i <= value)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I need. I might have  googeld using the wrong searchterm.

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for `takeWhile`

```
List<Integer> evens = IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i * 2)  //1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32...
                               .takeWhile(i -> i <= 1000)
                               .boxed()
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 5):

In all your shown cases, you didn't use the `iterate()'s` method that allowed a conditional.  So if someone is still not not up to Java 9, it can be done like this:

- Get the even values up to and including 20.

```
List<Integer> evens = IntStream.iterate(0, i->i<=20, i->i+2)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(evens);
```

- get fibonacci series less than 100

```
List<Long> fibs = Stream.iterate(new long[]{1,1}, f->f[1] < 100,f -> new long[] 
               {f[1], f[0] + f[1]})
     .mapToLong(f -> f[1])
     .boxed()
     .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(fibs);
```

- get the powers of 2 up to and including 128.

```
List<Integer> powersOfTwo = IntStream.iterate(1, i-> i <= 128, i -> i * 2)  //1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32...
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
System.out.println(powersOfTwo);
```

Prints

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128]
```